# How do i remove and add a class of a div in a particular viewport using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

This is my structure

```
<div class="container-lg">
<div class="row">
...
</div>
</div>
```

And i want to replace the CONTAINER-LG, Like this

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
...
</div>
</div>
```

when the viewport goes anything below 768px using jquery

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).on('resize', function(event) {
    var width = $(window).width();
    if(width < 768) {
        $(".container-lg").attr('class', 'container');
    } else {
        $(".container").attr('class', 'container-lg');
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks for answering but it rather added container to the container-lg.
it rather became 
<div class="container-lg container">
...
</div>

Comment: I just edited the code. Try this instead and let me know if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove class and add class using jQuery:

```
var width = $(window).width();
if(width < 768) {
    $('.container-lg').addClass('container').removeClass('container-lg');
} else {
    $('.container').addClass('container-lg').removeClass('container');
}
```

Comment: yours worked ok too, It performed the task i wanted. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @EbbyS.V.Hesse, no worries. But please have a read of this: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: I just checked well and i have seen that 

The code is changing CONTAINER-LG to CONTAINER, that is right but at the same time it also changing CONTAINER to CONTAINER-LG....

Comment: Yes, it behaves the other way if your window width changes from being narrower than 768px to being wider than that. If you do not want that behaviour, you can remove the `else` part of the `if` statement. That just means, your div will have the `container` class once the window width is less than 768px, and it will stay that way regardless of further adjusment to the screen width.

Comment: @EbbyS.V.Hesse, did I answer your question?